# jquery datepicker doesn't show on dynamically added input

Tags: jquery-ui, dom, dynamic, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-append

I have a table which each cells is a part of a form. In my form i have a jquery datepicker apply on a input element:

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                     ....
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="date" name="test"/>
                        </td>
                     ....
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <button type="button" id="addLine">Add line</button>
                <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

I add my datepicker like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#date').datepicker({showAnim: "slideDown"});   
        });
```

Here comes the problem... i want to add a line to my table but the datepicker doesn't apply on the new added line...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#addLine').click(function() {
                var line = $('<tr>...<input type="text" id="date" name="test"/>...</tr>');
                $('table').append(line);
              });
        });
```

The new line appears but when i want to insert a value the datepicker doesn't pop out on the new created line.

i've tried to put a another $('#date').datepiker()... in my .click(function... but it doesn't work. I've also tried to refresh the dom with a method called page().. but i've got a error that the method doesn't exist on the element. I need your help!

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have multiple ids with the same value, which might be causing some of your problems.  Use a class name instead, for example `class="date"`

```
<input type="text" class="date" name="test"/>
```

Since you are dynamically adding the content, after it is loaded you can then fire the `datePicker` function.

So:

```
line.find(".date").datepicker({showAnim: "slideDown"})
```

Sample: http://jsbin.com/omoyiy/2/edit